# Add data from map into a list of list of components

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a map in following structure.

```
const myMap = {
    "title1": [
        {
            name: 'one'
        },
        {
            name: 'two'
        },
    ],
    "title2": null,
    "title3": [
        {
            name: 'three'
        },
        {
            name: 'four'
        },
    ],
}
```

I want to convert the above to become a list of list of components as follows.

```
[
    // this array data came from the key title1 as it is first in map
    [
        <MyComponent name={name}/>, // name is 'one'
        <MyComponent name={name}/>, // name is 'two'
    ],
    // this array data came from the key title3 as it is next in map. title2 doesn't show up as its null 
    [
        <MyComponent name={name}/>, // name is 'three'
        <MyComponent name={name}/>, // name is 'four'
    ],
]
```

How can I achieve this?

At present attempted following which is not showing the data as expected.

```
<div>
{ myMap && Object.keys(myMap).forEach(key => {
        const array = myMap[key];
        array.forEach(obj => {
            return <MyComponent name={obj.name}/>
        })
    })
}
</div>
```

Comment: Maybe return the `array` from the outer `forEach`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use `map` inside the outer `map` too:

```js
const myMap = {
    title1: [
      {
        name: "one",
      },
      {
        name: "two",
      },
    ],
    title2: null,
    title3: [
      {
        name: "three",
      },
      {
        name: "four",
      },
    ],
  },
  MyComponent = ({ name }) => <div>{name}</div>,
  generate = (myMap) => {
    return (
      <div>
        {myMap &&
          Object.keys(myMap).map((key) => {
            const array = myMap[key],
              temp =
                array &&
                array.map((obj) => {
                  return <MyComponent name={obj.name} />;
                });

            return (array && <div class="sep">{temp}</div>);
          })}
      </div>
    );
  };

ReactDOM.render(generate(myMap), document.getElementById("root"));
```

```css
.sep{ outline: 1px solid red; margin: 5px; }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

It's really simple. You have to declare a method like this:

```
let listComponent = (myMap) => {
    let keys = Object.keys(myMap)
    let list = []
    keys.forEach(item => {
        list.push(myMap[item].map((obj,i) => (<MyComponent key={i} name={obj.name}/>))
    })
    return list;
}
```

And then use this function wherever you want your list component as `{listComponent(myMap)}`

Note: `key={i}` is not adviceable use unique id as key.